# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$x' on 'CommandLineAPI': due to the use of special Characters

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

Sample text :

```
test > test's done> test's done again's done
```

The synatx I'm using to capture it :

```
$x("//*[contains(text(),....)
```

when I replace the dots with that text I get the below error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$x' on 'CommandLineAPI': due to the use of special Characters
```

I tried escaping with `\` and `\'` in each embedded **`'`** which didn't work either

```
$x("//*[contains(text(),'test > test'\''s done> test'\''s done again'\''s done')]")
```

Comment: XPath doesn’t have any way of escaping special characters, Use double quotes instead of single quotes in the XPath expression `$x("//*[contains(text(),\"test > test's done> test's done again's done\")]")`